# How to use Laravel's automatic constructor injection while passing parameters to `make`?

Tags: laravel, ioc-container

I have a class called `GeneralReport` that has two constructor arguments:

`public function __construct(array $input, GeneralReportQueryBuilder $builder)`

One is the array of input (that the controllers can pass), and the other is a `GeneralReportQueryBuilder` that I want Laravel to pass in automatically. The problem is that if I pass the arguments to `make` like this:

`App::make('generalReport', [$input]);`

Then the second argument, an instance of `GeneralReportQueryBuilder`, is not passed by Laravel's `IOC Container` automatically.

How can I achieve this? I don't want the user to have to manually instantiate and pass in this dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem lay with my design.

The arguments passed to the constructor should only be dependencies – objects without which this class will not function. However, since I was using the single-responsibility principle, and I had only one public method (called `calculate()`), the correct place for these arguments was lost to me. In other words, since this object got an array of inputs and acted on those, the array seemed like a dependency, but in fact it wasn't; it was merely what its name suggests: input.

So, the correct place to pass in the `$input` parameter is straight to the `calculate()` method, not the constructor.

So, I changed my constructor to:

`public function __construct(GeneralReportQueryBuilder $builder)`

And I changed my `calculate()` function signature to:

`public function calculate(array $input)`

Neat!